# Merging several ASCII (.asc) files together and then converting it to a GeoTIFF (.tif)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, raster-conversion

In QGIS I'm trying to merge several ASCII (.asc) ESRI files in REGCAN95 (EPSG:4083) projection together to make one big file, and then convert it to GeoTIFF (.tif) in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) projection for use in an orthographic scenery generator (Ortho4XP).

So far I have tried importing the .asc files as raster layers (Layer>Add Layer>Add Raster Layer). I then use (Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge), select all the layers and save it as a .tif. I then use (Raster>Conversion>Translate) with the output projection set to WGS84 (EPSG:4326).

However when I attempt to use the resulting file in the scenery generator, it generates a completely flat landscape as if the elevation data has been lost. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this in QGIS, or using an alternative method to achieve this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the resulting TIF has minimum and maximum values less that the input ASC files?  These data will be available via Layer Propreties - Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon what was causing the issue. I solved it by opening settings>Options>Rendering>Contrast Enhancement and changing Algorithm to 'No Stretch' and Limits to 'Minimum/Maximum'. Causing the Histogram/Contrast to no longer become skewed, fixing the erroneous elevation data points.